# berryconda Pi Camera

Tags: pi-3, picamera

I recently installed berryconda python 3.6 on my Rasp pi b+ And now my programs for accessing the Pi camera do not work. I know I have the pi camera enabled thru theses steps:

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-picamera/5

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'picamera'
```

I think IDLE 3.5 is installed on the pi as well but I dont know how to run a command to use 3.5 Vs berryconda 3.6

The command I use in terminal to run my pi camera script is `CAMERA=pi python app.py`

Thanks for any tips and help...

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late for you but it might help others.
For me, the issue was solved by simply installing `picamera` in the `conda` environment.

```
conda activate
pip install picamera
```

Note, this installs `picamera` to your `conda` environment alongside the default python module in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`.